# Installing ngx admin panel template

Tags: templates, npm-install

I'm trying to install [NGX admin panel](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin) through NPM but I get this error at the end:

[image: Screenshot of error from npm]

Comment: what OS are you running on, can you please give more details.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Antz_shrek Windows 10

Comment: @Adriano
why? what is the problem in my question

Answer (score 1):

A brief note on the built-in Windows configuration

The Node installer installs, directly into the npm folder, a special piece of Windows-specific configuration that tells npm where to install global packages. When npm is used to install itself, it is supposed to copy this special `builtin` configuration into the new install. There was a bug in some versions of npm that kept this from working, so you may need to go in and fix that up by hand. Run the following command to see where npm will install global packages to verify it is correct.

```
npm config get prefix -g
```

If it isn't set to `<X>:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm`, you can run the below command to correct it:

```
npm config set prefix "${APPDATA}/npm" -g
```

Sometimes npm's cache gets confused, you will need to check whether the `.npmrc` file exists in your system (in `C://Users/Admin`). If yes, then remove that file and restart your command prompt and run 2 commands as follows:

```
"npm cache clear --force"
```

You might want to set your proxy server to:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy-server-address:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy-server-address:8080
```

But above all, I will advice you update your `npm`

```
npm -g install npm@latest
```

You might want to read more from [Troubleshooting](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows)